# Shorten SCSS import path in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, configuration

When I created a component, which is nested in a deep level, and if I want to import a shared `.scss`, I have to import it with a long path, likes:

`@import '../../../app.shared.scss';`

That doesn't happen with the `.ts` file, as I can config in `tsconfig.json`

```
"paths": {
    "*": [
        "src/*",
        "src/app/*",
    ]
},
```

then instead of import the full path in Typescript

`import { AppService } from '../../../app.shared';`

I can do it a lot simpler

`import { AppService } from 'app.shared';`

Is there any possible way to do the same with `scss` importation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this in angular-cli.json under options. Here a/b are folder.

```
 "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/styles/a/b"
              ]
            },
```

If test.scss file is inside folder b, you can write @import 'test' in your scss file.