# angular.json includePaths is not workings for node_modules

Tags: angular, sass

I have an angular library with styles that I want to use as if they were part of the application.
I tried using includePaths in order to do this by using the following configuration in angular.json:

```
{
    projects: {
        "my-project": {
                "root": "",
                "sourceRoot": "src",
                "prefix": "mp",
                "architect": {
                    "build": {
                        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                        "options": {
                            "outputPath": "dist/selenium-agent-ui",
                            "index": "src/index.html",
                            "main": "src/main.ts",
                            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                                "includePaths": [
                                    "src/assets",
                                    "node_modules/ui-library/assets"
                                ]
                            },
...
```

In my scss style files I'd like to write the following:

```
@import "assets/ui-library-folder/ui-library-scss-file"
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import "assets/ui-library-folder/ui-library-scss-file";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\app\app.component.scss 1:9  root stylesheet
```

Folder structure:

```
my-app
|--node_modules
|  |--ui-library
|  |  |--assets
|  |  |  |--ui-library-folder
|  |  |  |  |--ui-library-scss-file.scss
|--src
|  |--app
|  |  |--app.component.scss
|  |--assets
|  |  |--...
|--angular.json
|--package.json
|--tsconfig.json
|--tsconfig.app.json
```

I've tried working according to the solutions provided in these links but they do not work:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-shortcut-to-importing-styles-files-in-components

[Angular 8 ignores includePaths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57306476/angular-8-ignores-includepaths)

[Shorten SCSS import path in Angular 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54671565/shorten-scss-import-path-in-angular-7)

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5798

[How to short path to file in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59661754/how-to-short-path-to-file-in-angular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was the path included assets

replace:

```
"src/assets",
"node_modules/ui-library/assets"
```

with

```
"src",
"node_modules/ui-library"
```

**or** change the import paths. i.e.:

```
@import "ui-library-folder/ui-library-scss-file";
```

instead of:

```
@import "assets/ui-library-folder/ui-library-scss-file"
```

Comment: How to reference external `node_modules` css? I use Angular library which contains component using external css: `@import "3rd_party_node_module/its_styles/style.css`, but once I install my Angular library into my Angular app - this points to `https://localhost:4201/3rd_party_node_module/its_styles/style.css` instead of `node_modules/3rd_party_node_module/its_styles/style.css`

Comment: @Alexander,
Not sure but it seems related to your Webpack configuration. Do you use a custom configuration in addition to angular.json or a third-party builder?
It looks like when the packaging process was done the URL was converted to point to a separate file.
I would start by checking the build result rather than the code. Does the build result separate third-party vendors to separate packages?
You'll need to understand better the parts related to your Webpack css loader/plugin in order to answer your question

Comment: I ended up with referencing this 3rd party node module in `package.json` and `ng-package.json` within `dependencies` and `allowedNonPeerDependencies` option correspondingly. After that everything was normal.