Angular 17 - Can't find stylesheet to import (After Angular Upgrade)
I have found everything related to angular material theming, however, it's not the case.
After Angular 16 upgrade to Angular 17 I cannot import some styles from a specific node_module.
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): Can't find stylesheet to import.
Everything was working fine before the upgrade
Example import: @import '@package/src/components/specific-component';
If the scss file in node_module that I'm trying to import doesn't have any imports inside of it, everything works without any errors, however, if it has - I get provided error.
specific-component.scss (from node_module) - that would give an error, if I tried importing it in my own scss
@import 'mixins';

.specific-class {
  @include something();
}

specific-component.scss - that works and imports normally as before.
//@import 'mixins';

.specific-class {
  color: white;
}

Anyone encountered something similar and resolved that?

what is the angular exact version?

Angular 17.3.10

Please try below configuration in your angular.json file (path: projects..architect.build.options.stylePreprocessorOptions)
Configuration:
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
"includePaths": [
"."
]
}

Make sure you have added the paths of the scss files you want to use in the stylePreprocessorOptions, includePaths inside angular.json.
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
   "includePaths": [
     "src/styles",
     "src/assests/styles"
  ]
}

Then try importing them like.
@import 'mixins.scss';

.specific-class {
  @include something();
}


perhaps this is the correct solution if styles are local, but I'm taking these styles from node_module,
"includePaths": [
                "node_modules"
              ]

I have already added it in stylePreprocessorOptions, however, with no luck :/

the example files I provided are the example .scss files in the specific node_module that I'm taking from

@mimasik If you want to do like that, you have to also add the mixin path that example.scssuses, which is also located in the node_,modules folder

Isn't there a way to add everything from that node package? Because that mixin is importing other files (like variables, etc.), so if I would use multiple styles scss files that "includePaths" could get quite huge.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69218193/angular-json-includepaths-is-not-workings-for-node-modules
I found some similar issue, however, the solution doesn't work for me in angular 17

@mimasik usually when there are a lot of scss files, there is a barrel file like index.scss that contain all the scss imported into it, you can add this path and all the files will get imported
